# How to remove src attribute of iframe on a lightbox using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

A few days ago I asked here about how to add src attribute to iframe using jQuery. I actually got a code but it's not working. I have just started studying jQuery so maybe, I thought, there was something I missed. Now I got a code that's working, but the problem is when I close the lightbox, the video on the iframe continues streaming... How do I fix it? Here's my current code:

```
$("#presentation").click(function(){

     $("#iframe-presenter").get(0).contentWindow.location.href ='example.com';

});

$(".Close").click(function(){

     $("#iframe-presenter").get(0).contentWindow.location.href = '#';

});
```

I am thinking of refreshing the page in the event of closing the lightbox, but I think it's too distractive. Any help pls?...

**UPDATE:**

Ok so this one works:

```
$("#iframe-presenter").remove();
```

However, when relaunching the lightbox no video will appear since the code snippet above removes the iframe wich is `#iframe-presenter`. My solution now is:

```
$('.Close').after('<iframe id="iframe-presenter" src="example.com"></iframe>');
```

As you can see, jQuery now creates the iframe markup instead of HTML. So when I close the lightbox, it would still be able to load the iframe. But, it seems to load two streams at the same time even on first launch?

**UPDATE 2:**

Solved. `.Close` is a class so I made an ID for it...

Comment: Your code actually works? Have a look http://www.jsfiddle.net/NG6kV/1/

Comment: @jAndy: yah it works, with regards to closing the lightbox. But in killing the iframe content(a video stream), it doesn't work...

Comment: I don't get you. Setting the `.src` of the iframe to an empty string will clear the whole thing like in the link I posted above, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
$(".Close").click(function(){
      $("#iframe-presenter").get(0).contentWindow.remove()
});
```

or

```
$(".Close").click(function(){

     $("#iframe-presenter").get(0).contentWindow.location.href = 'javascript:;';

});
```

Comment: care to elaborate? i'll try to help you if you let me know what the problem is now